# youtube selenium comments scraping

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, youtube, comments

```
#open the webpage
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trsklC1i0Js")


C =pd.DataFrame()

          
all_noc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[1]/h2/yt-formatted-string/span[1]')
all_noc = [x.text for x in all_noc]
noc = pd.Series(all_noc)
   
    
all_comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
all_comments = [x.text for x in all_comments]
comments = pd.Series(all_comments)
    
    
    


    

df = pd.DataFrame({"No. Of Comments":noc, "Comments":comments})
C = C.append(df) 
time.sleep(2)
C
```

I want to extract all the comments on a video
there are more than 300 comments
and
YouTube do not load the page at a time
How can load the full page and **scrape** all the comments from a video

Comment: YouTube is not meant for scraping at all. Why do you wanna do that anyway  ?

Comment: office work
help me in scraping all the 
comments
title of video 
likes 
dislikes 
views
from youtube